# callback after each post is executed in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop to fetch data via $post. And after all the data is fetched, I need to have a callback function. My current code only callback first then and post. How can I do it the other way round?

```
function addMegaMenu(callback){
    $('#megamenu > ul > li').each(function(){
        $.post('/_menu.cfm',  function(data){
           console.log("post exec");
        })
    });
    callback.apply();
}
function addMobileIcon(){
    console.log("callback exec");
}
$(function(){
    addMegaMenu(function(){
        addMobileIcon();
    });
})
```

It prints out:

```
callback exec
post exec
```

I need to make it:

```
post exec
callback exec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a list of deferreds, each `$.post` will return a deferred...

```
$.post('/_menu.cfm',  ... in a loop
```

When you have that promise list:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function(d) {
         console.log("done", this, d);
    }, function(e) {
         console.log("failed");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to wait until all elements have done their callback, you have to keep track of how many outstanding POST requests there are:

```
var counter = 0;
function addMegaMenu(callback){
    $('#megamenu > ul > li').each(function(){
        counter++;
        $.post('/_menu.cfm',  function(data){
            counter--;           
            console.log("post exec");
            if (counter==0) {
                callback.apply();
            }
        })
    });
}
function addMobileIcon(){
    console.log("callback exec");
}
$(function(){
    addMegaMenu(function(){
        addMobileIcon();
    });
})
```